# Rails Separate Sessions Over Multiple Subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, subdomain

This is Ruby on Rails specific

Has anyone had for example 2 subdomains, test1.example.com and test2.example.com, you can login to test1.example.com by using the login form on test1.example.com, then go to test2.example.com login page in another browser, dont login, go back to 1.example.com, refresh the page, then be logged out?

Im using active_record_store with domain set to ".example.com"

```
config.session_store :active_record_store, :key => '_example_session', :domain => ".example.com"
```

The above is set in development.rb environment settings, I did the same for the session_store.rb file just in-case.

Comment: Yea I actually did, forgot to update this thread...turned out to be an issue with acts as tenant gem I was using. Are you having a similar issue?